# How to change Codec ID with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, id

Now I have a mpeg4 file with Codec ID 'isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)'.
I need to remake its ID to 'mp42' (I have to save all other settings without changes).
what commands I should use in FFmpeg to do this?

---

here is what I have in MediaInfo:
[the screenshot of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiXRw.png)

Comment: `mpg42` or `mp42`?

Comment: mp42, not mpg42

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That field is [actually](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfoLib/issues/978) called the major brand. You can use the -brand option to change it.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -brand mp42 out.mp4
```

Comment: thank you, I did it and I see now 'Codec ID' as 'mp42' in the General partition of MediaInfo, but in the Video partion, it's still 'avc1' (please, check 'the screenshot of settings' above). Should I change the codec to re-format it?

Comment: That will remain `avc1`. There is no MP4 video codec with id `mp42`